# Should i catch std::logic_error?

Tags: c++, exception, logic

Im aware of the difference between std::runtime_error and std::logic_error.

So the question arose whether i should catch std::logic_error or not since those exceptions should never be thrown in the first place if there is no bug in the code. Do these exceptions only exist for developing purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would catch it, but in debug builds either dump the call-stack or re-throw it [so the application exits with a "uncaught exception"]. In release builds, the catcher should print a message that gives a hint as to what happened, and that the user should report the problem.

My thinking here is that since it's (at least sometimes) possible that your application will hit these sort of unusual use-case that you haven't hit. Just exiting with a "uncaught exception" is really not a very user-friendly behaviour. So doing something "a little less harsh" is always a good idea - even if there really is nothing you can do to correct the error in the code, it's nice if there's some explanation to the user about what happened in a language that the user (who is probably not a programmer) can understand.